# How to draw debug lines in OpenGL 3.3 Core profile

Tags: opengl

Because of Mac OS support of my program, I can't use compatibility profile in OpenGL 3.3 therefore I can't use glBegin, glVertex, glEnd for quick debug. I just want to draw bounding boxes for my models and some lines for debug stuff. Should I prepare vertex buffers, shaders etc. everytime I want to draw quick stuff, or is there any easy way for debug drawing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really can't draw in the core profile without having a VAO, vertex data in a VBO, etc. And a shader program, of course.

Well, technically speaking, you can draw without VAO/VBO by hardwiring vertices in the vertex shader code. But that's really not very practical, IMHO.

If you frequently have the need to draw a few lines for debugging, I would write a little helper class to handle that. It could provide an interface to add pairs of points that define a line, and to draw all the lines that were added. Everything needed to draw the lines, like creating a trivial shader program, VAO, VBO, can be hidden in the implementation.

This might take an hour to write the first time. But once you have it, you can simply drop it into your projects, and use it wherever you need the functionality.